# USB CDC example with pic18f4550

Tags: pic, usb, communication, usb-device, mplabx

I need help with USB CDC communication with [PIC18F4550](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/39632e.pdf), xc8 compiler.

I downloaded that files on this link: http://www.microchip.com/forums/m679588-p2.aspx

It works, but doesn't have all the files, like main.c. Is there someone that can give an example?

Answer (score 1):

I was in the same situation only recently and [Microchip Libraries for Applications](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=2680&dDocName=en547784) contains complete working USB examples including CDC. One thing to be aware of is that some of the USB libraries don't appear to have been updated to support XC8. I was targetting a PIC18F14K50 and received numerous compiler errors so ended up installing the older C18 compiler which is still available at [MPLAB C Compiler for PIC18 MCUs](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1406&dDocName=en010014).

I imagine getting it to work under XC8 would be possible but it looked like a reasonably substantial amount of work. I did notice references to XC8 in various parts of the USB stack so maybe you won't have the same problem with a PIC18F4550.